# ffmpeg - how can I capture the timestamp of a screenshot using a seek and finding the nearest iframe?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I've tried various different methods. ffprobe has always shown sensical results, with the pts_time increasing as the frames go on, using this command:

```
ffprobe -show_frames video.mp4 > probestats.txt
```

I thought about using that data to find the video frame nearest to the seconds I'm seeking to in ffmpeg, but I am trying to keep this performant, as I'm generating thumbnails on uploads that could exceed 5GB, which means I would end up with 50MB+ probe files to parse.

So, currently, I'm looping over this ffmpeg command, so as to end up with 10 thumbnails total per file, regardless of length:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -ss 00:00:05 -vf select="eq(pict_type\\,I)[s1];[s1]showinfo[out]" -vframes 1 -q:v 1 thumbs/thumb-1.jpg 2>&1
```

The aim is to get the nearest iframe of the seconds I'm seeking to, e.g. find the nearest iframe near the 5 second mark and take a thumbnail -- which gives some increased performance.

The issue is, ffmpeg is outputting seemingly random pts_time's, definitely not correct compared to the pkt_pts_time shown in ffprobe.

So as the title states, I'm looking for an ffmpeg command to generate a thumbnail at the nearest iframe to a specified seek, and get the timestamp.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way you're doing it now it's not optimal as you're seeking the output, that is the input video gets decoded and discarded until you hit the seek mark.

The optimal way to do this is by input seeking, that is putting the `-ss` argument before the input `-i` and using the `-noaccurate_seek` option. In this way the input is **parsed, and not decoded, using keyframes**.

Thus it'll seek to the nearest keyframe preceding your timestamp which you can then save to an image. [See the wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking) for more info.

```
ffmpeg -noaccurate_seek -ss 00:00:05 -i video.mp4 \
-vf select="eq(pict_type\\,I)[s1];[s1]showinfo[out]" \
-vframes 1 -q:v 1 thumbs/thumb-1.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. One thing I still can't get to work is the pts_time from the showinfo command. e.g. seeking to 38 seconds gives me pts_time:0.580247 and seeking to 5 seconds gives me pts_time:1.58992 -- am I misunderstanding what pts_time is? I have read the docs but am not sure if I'm fully understanding what these values are.

Comment: When you seek in output (`-ss` after `-i`) the `pts_time` is the actual time of the I-frame as it should be. When you seek the input (`-ss` before `-i`) it seems to be the offset  between the seek timestamp and the actual I-frame `pts_time`. Not sure if it's intentional or just a byproduct of seeking via parsing.

Comment: You can check the I-frame positions with `ffprobe -select_streams v -i video.mp4 -show_frames | grep key_frame=1 -A2`. See if they match the offsets.

Answer (score 1):

I am late to this thread, but I'm also trying to process thumbnails in the fastest way possible. I tried many methods, including the one by @aergistal, but this one was about 3x faster for me:

```
-hide_banner
-loglevel panic
-ss #{timestamp}
-i #{path}
-vframes 1
-f image2 #{folder}/#{s}-#{timestamp.gsub(':', '_')}.jpg
```